# Why dropping a primary key is not dropping its unique index?

Tags: oracle, unique-constraint, composite-primary-key

1. I have a table with `Col1` and `Col2` as a composite primary key `pk_composit_key` and a unique index that was automatically created for the constraint.
2. I then altered the table to add new column `Col3`.
3. I dropped the `pk_composit_key` constraint:

   ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT pk_composit_key;
4. Now, When I tried to insert records I got `ORA-00001: unique constraint pk_composit_key violated`.

   - Why am I getting that error?
   - When the key was dropped why wasn't the unique index dropped automatically?

Comment: Were the records you inserted just violating the new three-value composite key, which will have an index with the same name anyway? You can't do what you've said. If the index was created automatically by the first constraint it would have been dropped. If it was created manually before the constraint then it would remain after the drop, but the creation of the second constraint would have failed, because the existing index now doesn't match the constraint columns.

Comment: @AlexPoole when we drop constraint, the index still exists there. then when we try to insert new record, it says unique index violation. I updated the question slightly

Comment: You get a unique index violation when you try to break the constraint, that's normal. Are you now saying you get that error before you tried to recreate the primary key? Or after it was recreated? How did you check it still existed after the initial drop? At the moment I'm not sure if you're just misinterpreting the error you get, when you insert data that does actually have duplicate col1,col2,col3 values; or if you haven't recreated the constraint, whether you created the index manually the first time.

Comment: @AlexPoole I got Error at step 4 while inserting. No new Constraint created yet. I can list that index name in user_indexes.

Comment: can you create a test case, containing all the create table, constraint, etc statements, which reproduces the issue, please? That way, we can try repeating the same steps for ourselves, which will allow us to provide you with better help.

Comment: @AlexPoole, I can't reproduce the issue , because i tried to created but such behavior is not observed in dev environment. Is there anything to do with export and import of the schema?

Comment: @touchchandra - yes, that could have created the index before the constraint. I can't remember if it's imp or impdp that can do that, it's a while since i've seen it. Original import I think. Can you confirm that's what you used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You mentioned exporting and importing the schema, and if that happened in the environment that showed this behaviour it would explain what you're seeing; at least if you used legacy `imp` rather than the data pump `impdp`.

[The original import documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#SUTIL3669) states the order objects are imported:

> Table objects are imported as they are read from the export dump file. The dump file contains objects in the following order:
>
> - Type definitions
> - Table definitions
> - Table data
> - Table indexes
> - Integrity constraints, views, procedures, and triggers
> - Bitmap, function-based, and domain indexes

So the unique index would have been imported, then the constraint would have been created.

[When you drop a primary key constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52197):

> - If the primary key was created using an existing index, then the index is not dropped.
> - If the primary key was created using a system-generated index, then the index is dropped.

Because of the import order, the constraint is using an existing index,so the first bullet applies; and the index is retained when the constraint is dropped.

You can use the [`drop index` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF53209) to drop the index even if it wasn't created automatically:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT pk_composit_key DROP INDEX;
```

See also My Oracle Support note 370633.1; and 1455492.1 suggests similar behaviour will occur with data pump import as well. I'm not aware of any way to check if an index is associated with a constraint at this level; there is no difference in the `dba_constraints` or `dba_indexes` views when you create the index manually or automatically. Including `drop index` will make it consistent though.

Comment: Found this " Since you did an export and import, the import works by creating the index separate and then adding the primary key constraint separate. Since in case of import, the two thiings happen separately, dropping the primary key now will NOT drop the index."  https://community.oracle.com/message/1223619

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how unique index was created...below are the various ways and behaviour

1) first create unique index (on the column for which primary key to be defined) and then add the primary key constraint. In this situation your DDL to add the primary key will utilize the existing unique index. So when you drop the primary key it will not drop the index but only primary key. ==> this is your situation I guess...

2) While creating the table you define the primary key OR when you add the primary key when there was no existing unique index for the column(s) on which primary key to be defined, so system will create a unique index and use it for primary key. So in this case when you drop the primary key the unique index will also get dropped.

Comment: Except the question states the index was created automatically. Which may not be correct of course - in fact it's likely the description of what happened isn't quite right. Would have been an odd name for a standalone unique index though. (Also, [doc link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52197) for the behaviour).

Comment: Yes @AlexPoole, My assumption was that unique constraint was created automatically while creating constraint. Can we confirm, whether its created manually or automatically?

Comment: if constraint or index is created by system automatically then it will have different naming convention (SYS%) the same will be shown in the error message it will not be pk_composit_key in error message.

Comment: @narendra, this is how table was created in production             CREATE TABLE DATA_SOURCE
(
    COL1    VARCHAR2(4),
    COL2    VARCHAR2(4),
    COL3    VARCHAR2(200),
    DATA1   VARCHAR2(30),
    DATA2   VARCHAR2(30)
    CONSTRAINT       PK_COMPOSIT_KEY  PRIMARY KEY (COL1, COL2) 
);

Comment: @narendra - only if it wasn't named; if you name the constraint the index name will match.

Comment: @AlexPoole, yes, i guess that is why the constraint and index names are same.

Comment: yes, constraint name and index name will be same in this case but if you drop the constraint the unique index will also be dropped.